# alert something whenever a checkbox is selected or checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've tried making a function that is triggered by whenever a checkbox inside a table is checked but that didn't work well. I've tried making a function located in a $(document).ready but it didn't also work.

this is my html code

```
<td id='row'><input type='checkbox' name='helloname' value="helloval" id='select'> hello </td>
```

this is my function

```
$(document.ready)(function () {
    $("#row input:checked'").each(function(){
        $('#select').click(function(){
           alert('clicked');
        });
    });
```

My main goal is counting the selected checkboxes and not allowing the user to check more than 3. But for now I'm trying to make a function that would recognize whenever a checkbox is selected
    });

Comment: your syntax for document.ready is wrong, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your DOM ready should be `$(document).ready(function(){...`
2. You shouldn't bind click to each checkbox by iterating through only checked ones
3. Bind using event delegation, and then check the state on click.

As per your question, your problem is to disallow user to check more than three checkboxes.

You could do that by doing a `length` of all checked inputs, and then overriding new checks if the length exceeds three:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/uERSd/1/***

```
// bind click to all input of type checkbox inside #row via delegation
$("#row").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    // check the length i.e. total number of inputs which are currently checked
    var tot = $("#row input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    if (tot > 3) {
        // disallow new checks if three are already checked
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To recognize whenever checkbox is selected, you can use:

```
$("#select").change(function() {
 if(this.checked) {
    alert('clicked');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Here `document.ready` syntax is corrected and jquery modified to get total count of checked checkboxes inside `td` with `id='row'`

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#row input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
          var count = $("#row input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
          alert("total checked checkbox is : "+count);
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work

```
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            $("#select").change(function() {
             if(this.checked) {
                alert('checked');
             }}); 
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<table class="tableTable">
<tr id="tableTr">
<td id='row'><input type='checkbox' name='helloname' value="helloval" id='select'> hello </td>
<td id='row1'><input type='checkbox' name='helloname' value="helloval" id='select1'> hello1 </td>
<td id='row2'><input type='checkbox' name='helloname' value="helloval" id='select2'> hello2 </td>
<td id='row3'><input type='checkbox' name='helloname' value="helloval" id='select3'> hello3</td>
 </tr>
    </table>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#tableTr").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
var count = $("#tableTr input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
if (count > 3) {
this.checked = false;
alert("only 3 items can be checked");
        }
    });
 });
```